# Video card dead/dying, works for short amount of time

Tags: graphics-card

I think my video card has died but I want to make sure before letting it go cheaply for parts etc.

One thing that makes me think it's not completely fried is that it will work as normal in a game for a short amount of time before everything freezes, glitches out sometimes, and forces me to manually reboot. Trying to get it to boot again immediately after this sort of crash was successful maybe 1/6 times. Waiting a short period of time allowed me to boot again. The fan also seems to work as normal while running.

Various glitches, weird cursors, stuff repeating while being dragged have been happening for awhile before this.

Everything runs fine without the card in.

I have: changed PCIe slots, done various clean reinstalls of driver versions, cleaned it of dust and reseated the heatsink/fan to no improvements

I haven't tried a different power supply and/or motherboard.

Is there any software out there that could point me in the dirrection of the real problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting the card in a different PCIe slot, if you have an open slot available? I've had a fairly similar issue before, and have answered a few other questions similar to this. Most of them had their issue resolved by changing to a different PCIe slot.

Comment: I also tried that, didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should try to determine the source of the problem.  If you have a spare video card, put it in your PC.  If the PC runs fine, then the problem is most likely the card.  If the PC does not run properly, then the issue is most likely your PC, not the card.  Alternatively, you can put "bad" the video card into another PC and see of the same issues are exhibited.

A very common cause for video cards failure is overheating.  You can google for software that will show the card's temperature as it is working.  As for the video card itself, use canned air to blow off any dust, especially in and around the fan.  Sometimes the thermal paste between the GPU and the heat sink expires.  Carefully remove the fan and any connectors holding the heat sink to the GPU.  Clean the thermal paste off with a some alcohol on a rag and let it dry.  Then reapply the thermal paste and reattach all the components.  Plug the card back into the PC and test.

Lack of enough power could be another problem.  However, most video cards will simply turn off if they are not getting enough power.  Also, they would work after a reboot and not under a heavy load.  From the way you worded your post, it sounds like it worked properly in the past, so I doesnt sound like this is the issue.